# Structural Navigation with no extensions in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, visual-studio-2019

I used Idea products for a long time, they have one feature called Structural navigation that allows going forward to the next context when you are typing. I Mean if I click some part of my code, I can just press tab and go to the next statement, write code, press tab, etc. etc.

Is there something that works similarly with Visual Studio 2019 (no extensions like Resharper just visual)

[image]

Comment: Too bad this doesn't exist in VS. Great feature...